# How to prevent Mac from changing keyboard layout when changing USB keyboards?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have two USB "PC"-keyboards (Swedish) that I regularly connect to my Mac. I can configure either to be of the correct type, "ISO", but when I have configured the first, the other has the wrong layout. The way that it is wrong is that the key right of the left Shift and the key below Escape are swapped: If I configure keyboard 1. to be correct, keyboard 2. has them swapped and vice versa. Is there a way to prevent this?

It is particularly annoying since if I configure either of the keyboards, the "Change Keyboard Type..." button is removed from the Keyboard settings menu. So what I have to do is to remove the `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` file *and reboot*. Meaning, if I want to switch keyboards I have to: 1. remove the file, 2. reboot, 3. reconfigure.

My system: MacBook Pro, macOS: Ventura 13.3.1 (a)

Comment: Do they both show the same Input Source? Can you connect both at once & see if you can at that point get it to recognise them correctly? [The only place you can tell it can see both is in Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts > Modifier keys.] Are the keyboards identical? Are both definitely Swedish ISO [PC]? (I'm trying to figure out why it might think one is ANSI, which would be an indicator of your 'swapped' keys.)